# How to enable searchable select box in table row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image][image] Here in the table I have used searchable select below item name. On clicking add item button above the new row is inserted by default values. But what happens is select in first row only works while in second row dropdown menu of select option does not open.

I think the problem comes that I am unable to assign different ids to the select.

```
<!-- searchable select 2 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- searchable select 2 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

**Function of Add Item**

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

          var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

          newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

          switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                newcell.childNodes[0].id = "aa"+rowCount;
                break;
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;

          }

        }
      }
```

**Select HTML**

```
[![<td>

 <select type="select-one" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" data-live-search="true" data-container="body" data-show-subtext="true" name="item_details[]">
    <option value="1"> Computer </option>
    <option value="2"> Laptop </option>
    <option value="3"> Mouse </option>
    <option value="4"> Keyboard </option>
    <option value="5"> Writer </option>
  </select>

</td>][2]][2]
```

Comment: Are you using any plugin for select?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap select

Comment: Can you provide the plugin link for the same?

Comment: check it now i have added links

Comment: Try the answer I have provided below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here what I have used clone method to accomplish this task. And below is the `addRow()` function that I have changed.

> addRow() Function with clone method of jquery.

```
function addRow() {

    var row = $('.new_item_row').last();

    var item_row_clone = $('.new_item_row').last().clone();
    item_row_clone.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    item_row_clone.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    item_row_clone.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
    item_row_clone.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    row.after(item_row_clone);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

After adding your select HTML to the DOM, you will need to refresh the select picker

More here http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Use might need to change the selector.

Comment: Actually i am not removing any option nor adding.But adding new select in new row so the problem comes is programatically select cannot identify itself so i want to give them unique ID. But how could i do this ?

Comment: Check out my add row function where in switch case I have tried to assign ID to select but it does not get it. So how could i differentiate between select?

Comment: @KhushalNayani i think you need to change the `id` of `select` element instead of `select-one`. And then reinitialize the plugin..

Comment: `select-one` is just a random type given to identified the select by type in switch case

Comment: you mean instead of `case "select-one":` -- `case "select":`